# Is it possible to disable ASP.NET website sleep in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I run my website in IIS and I've got some running timers with events there. (I know that it's bad design and plan to recode it however for now I want to check if there fast solution)

After some time website is going to sleep and that's why my timers events do nothing.

Is there IIS setting or another way to reject sleeping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this might be usefull to you as detailed here :-

http://forums.asp.net/t/1950241.aspx?ASP+NET+MVC+website+goes+to+sleep+How+to+nake+it+always+awake+

There are quite a few ways to set timeouts within .NET (Session Timeouts, Forms Authentication Timeouts and IIS-related Timeouts). Your issue most likely relates to the IIS Idle Timeout as mentioned below :

**Setting the Application IdleTimeout property within IIS :-**

You may need to check what your timeout is configured for within IIS, as this timeout will override the timeouts defined in your web.config.

Within IIS there is a setting called Idle Timeout, which defaults at 20 minutes. This could explain your early timeout issue.

[**Configuring the IdleTimeout property within IIS**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx)

Scott Hanselman also addresses strange issues that can occur when dealing with timeouts when using Forms Authentication in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx) as well.

Some other commonly encountered timeouts might be through the Session or Forms Authentication, which would be adjusted as seen below.

**Setting the SessionState Timeout within your web.config :-**

You can update the timeout property of your Session State (if that is what is actually timing out) within your web.config file in the  element as shown below (default of 20 minutes shown below):

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web> 
 <!-- Adjust the timeout property below -->
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState> 
 </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

**Setting the Forms Authentication Timeout within your web.config :-**

You can adjust the specific timeout property of your Forms Authentication in your application by adjusting the timeout property within the  element of your web.config file. You will also want to be mindful that if you are using the slidingExpiration property in conjunction with timeouts as they can actually expire much earlier than the timeout listed.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
 <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="yourTimeoutInMinutes"></forms> 
</authentication>
```

So if you wanted to extend the amount that the authentication token stays "alive" for to say 360 minutes (6 hours), you would set it as seen below :

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
 <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="360"></forms> 
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 3):

As said on this page https://aspnetfaq.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/ you can set the idle timeout to 0 (zero) to disable the website sleep.